# How do you prove RFC 791 - Internet Protocol

Tags: cisco, internet, cisco-catalyst, network-protocols

We are being asked to prove we are using RFC 791 (Internet Protocol) within our network.  How does one prove such a thing via documentation if there is no such document from the vendor stating as much....such as Cisco who built their entire company on this protocol....Specifically for the Cisco 9000 series switches...but also every single network card in the entire facility.

Comment: `We are being asked to prove we are using RFC 791`. Why?

Comment: That's a rather odd request. Who is asking for this proof?

Comment: This is a rather odd question and as currently stated, there might be multiple ways to go about it depending on what the actual need is. Please state the objective as closely as required by what appears to be an external auditor (?) and what it aims to truly demonstrate (ie. what the audit aims to verify, what the client requirement is...).